# 404 error after define welcome page with controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm studying Spring Boot Web Application using this [tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/how-to-create-a-spring-boot-web-application-spring-mvc-with-jsp-thymeleaf).
I create an d1.html in resources/static folder and a controller class as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Contacts</h1>
    <a href="/list_contact">Click here to list all contacts</a>
</body>
</html>


@Controller
public class HomeController {
     @RequestMapping("/")
    public String visitHome() {
        return "d1";
    }
}
```

But when I try to access localhost:8080 and it has a 404 error. I changed the return value to d1.html and this time it works.
Is this because of some configuration of my project? I searched the web and someone said it may be related to the application.yml, but I can't find that file in the project. Any help? Thx.

Comment: You should read about ViewResolver and InternalViewResolver for better understanding.

Comment: application.yaml is "an alternative" for application.properties....AND it is also important which dependencies (spring-boot-starters) you have "on board"! ;)

Comment: and by "resources/static" you mean `src/main/resources/static` !(? ..as the tutorial says)